# hacking whoami to return a fake username

Tags: linux, path, hadoop, hdfs

I've created a new `whoami` command which requires a fake username and have put it in the PATH by adding it to ~/.profile . It is created in a way that `whoami` is called before actual the actual whoami from Linux.

The main reason to do this is because I am remote accessing a Hadoop cluster and want the copied files to be under the fake username.

This works fine when I call `whoami` in the shell and even calling $PATH shows the path to my created whoami before everything else. But for some reason, when Hadoop is called, it doesn't pick the created `whoami'.

Can someone help me with how to fix this?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most applications do not use `whoami` to determine a user's username or group. For instance, in bash you can use the command `id` to find more detailed information about yourself or `id [username]` (such as `id root`) to find out more detailed information about other users. Groups can be found with `groups` as well. Also, different programming languages, such as C, have their own methods of determining user identities such as the `getuid()` command.

If you really "need" to go as far as faking your user account, you'll need to go down to OS level and create hooks into the kernel/API that handles those methods.

Is it possible that you simply `chown` the files after they are copied instead?

**UPDATE:**

It appears that some releases of Hadoop do actually use `whoami` (my own implementation w/ clustering does not).

In this event, the best (a term loosely used) suggestion would be to  move the legitimate `whoami` executable and create a `whoami` shell script that goes in it's place. The custom script should validate the current user and if it's "hadoop", return whatever faked username you want - otherwise return valid output. Igor's answer would work in this case.

Comment: Hadoop is using the `whoami` command, but reze is not able to set the new `whoami` command properly in the path so that Hadoop picks the right one.

Comment: Updated my answer to support Hadoop that uses `whoami` by suggesting a wrapper for the legitimate `whoami` script.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose that hadoop uses other `PATH` variable then you have in your shell.
You can tune its PATH and add the directory with fake `whoami` to its beginning.

When it is impossible, 
you can write a small wrapper for `whoami` (I'm not sure that it is a good idea but you can do this if you want) that will run original `whoami` except when the script is executed by hadoop:

```
#!/bin/sh
WHOAMI=/bin/whoami.orig
if [ "$($WHOAMI)" = hadoop ]
then
  echo fake
else
  exec $WHOAMI "$@"
fi
```

Comment: thanks. this is a great suggestion. Could you please let me know how to tune the right PATH of hadoop? I have no idea what else I should change?

Comment: There must be `hadoop-env.sh` in your hadoop installation. You must specify `PATH` there